# C# Reflection - Delegate in a generic class

Tags: c#, reflection

```
// case1
public class A<T> {
    public delegate bool Compare(T a, T b);
}

// case2
public class A {
    public delegate bool Compare<T>(T a, T b);
}

Test(typeof(A<>.Compare));
Test(typeof(A.Compare<>));

void Test(Type type)
{
    // #1
}
```

My Question:

How to write code in position #1 to tell type is case1 or case2?

It seems there is no difference between

```
typeof(A<>.Compare).GetGenericArguments()[0]
```

and

```
typeof(A.Compare<>).GetGenericArguments()[0]
```

Thanks!

-------------edit----------------

What I want is to tell where the T of type come from. Is T defined in A or defined in Compare itself?

There may be other more complex cases, for example

```
public class B<T> {
    public delegate bool Compare<X>(X a, T b);
}
```

In this case I want to know: X is defined on Compare, and T is defined on B.

Comment: Can't you just do `type == typeof(A<>.Compare)`? if it's false, it's the other one (depending on how specific it needs to be).

Comment: Thanks @LukeBriggs No, It needs to be 100% specific.Actually I need to know where does T come from.

Comment: What do you mean by being 100% specific? Do you mean you want to know if the type argument `T` is defined on the class or on the method? If so, it would be good if you update your question to make that clear because of now, it does not sound like you're asking for that.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @qiucw it's still a little ambiguous - you could have, say, `Compare<X,Y,T,S>`; is it the one named 'T' you want, or the 'first' one?

Comment: @LukeBriggs All generic parameters

Comment: @qiucw So you'd like to collect all generic parameters rather than spot one case over another? What do you need to output - an array of generic parameters?

Comment: @LukeBriggs I want the code. Given a type (a delegate), type.IsGenericTypeDefinition == true, type.BaseType.IsGenericTypeDefinition == true, how do I know each generic parameters of this type is defined on this type or on type.BaseType??

Comment: @qiucw Right ok, that's not what your question says ("to tell type is case1 or case2?" is something *very* different, and is what Rob's answer does)

Comment: @qiucw I'm not sure if that's possible. As far as I know, the nested definitions are populated from the declaring type. For example: `public delegate bool Compare<A>();` when inside `class A<T>` would create a type `A<T>.Compare<A,T>` even though you've explicitly only declared `A` on that method. At run time, there isn't a difference between the generic arguments declared on `Compare` or on `A`. You *could* compare names, but it's also valid to declare `Compare<T>()` when in `class A<T>` (which actually emits `Compare<T,T>()`)

Comment: Thank you very much @Rob.     * but it's also valid to declare Compare<T>() when in class A<T> *    Yes i noticed this as well... Thank you again, this answer is what I want...

Answer (score 2):

Check the declaring type:

```
void Test(Type type)
{
    if (type.DeclaringType.IsGenericType)
        Console.WriteLine("1"); 
    else 
        Console.WriteLine("2");
}
```